# run-time error '1004' on range selecting

Tags: vba, excel

I get run-time error '1004' on this code
sh2 is a specific sheet on another file. I don't want to activate the second sheet,just use it and then closing the file. I get my error on the else condition

```
If sh2.Range(sh2.Cells(1, y + 4), sh2.Cells(1, y + 4)) <> "" Then
                        y = y + 1
Else: sh2.Range(sh2.Cells(1, 4), sh2.Cells(114, (y + 4) - 1)).Select
                        Selection.Copy
```

When I'm trying to debug: the y is 49 (as it had to be) and the cells of the range under the else get their own and right values. Where is my error?

PS. I'm using excel 2013 and the y is set to 0 before this code

Comment: Please avoid the use of `.Select/.Activate` [INTERESTING READ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Answer (score 1):

try `sh2.Range(sh2.Cells(1, 4), sh2.Cells(114, (y + 4) - 1)).Copy` (without selecting)
i think you cannot select anything on the sheet unless you activate it

Answer (score 1):

Your original code worked for me - what happens if you drop the `Select`?

```
Dim sh2 As worksheet
Set sh2 = Sheets(2)

y = 49
If sh2.Range(sh2.Cells(1, y + 4), sh2.Cells(1, y + 4)) <> "" Then
    y = y + 1
Else
    sh2.Range(sh2.Cells(1, 4), sh2.Cells(114, (y + 4) - 1)).Copy
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you drop the `sh2.` from within the `sh2.range` it will work.

Change `sh2.Range(sh2.Cells(1, y + 4), sh2.Cells(1, y + 4))` to

`sh2.Range(Cells(1, y + 4), Cells(1, y + 4))`

Untested though

Comment: the error is on the range under the else, the first range is ok